# Subviews get messed up after superview height constraint changes

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I've challenged myself to replicate the UI of iOS Weather App. This is a dummy interface to show, say, humidity, in cities:

[image]

I am now on the stage where there is an upper container view (light gray) and a working scroll content (yellow with small rectangles) that can be dragged from the bottom. Upper container is set to have a height constraint of 2/3 of screen height and is pinned to superview on sides and top:

[image]

One of its subviews - the orange rectangle that will display humidity graphically - is set to have height of 1:1.8 of superview and width proportional to self height of 1:2. Here are all of the 'graph' constraints:

[image]

The idea is that when scrolling begins the orange rectangle gets transparent gradually (it works fine, so I won't put the code here) and smaller to some point where it gets hidden.

I was counting on the upper container view height constraint, so made an outlet for it:

```
@IBOutlet weak var upperContentHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

In my scrollViewDidScroll method I added the code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let scrollOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let newUpperContentViewHeight = upperContentViewHeight - scrollOffsetY
        upperContentHeightConstraint.constant = newUpperContentViewHeight

}
```

`upperContentViewHeight` is calculated in `viewDidLoad()` method, as it depends on screen height.

I expect the orange subview to get smaller in height and width as container view shrinks in height, because all their constraints are related to each other. But when scrolling starts, the upper content view and orange subview get messed up:

[image]

Whilst if I print upper view's height to console while scrolling, it shows that everything works fine:

```
Current offsetY: 0.5
new height: 378.0
Current offsetY: 6.0
new height: 372.5
Current offsetY: 14.5
new height: 364.0
Current offsetY: 20.0
new height: 358.5
Current offsetY: 22.0
new height: 356.5
Current offsetY: 24.5
new height: 354.0
```

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: here's a gif with the issue:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to add `layoutIfNeeded()` after changing constant?

Comment: Yes, behavior stays the same - still messed up.

Comment: Can you give me a gif ? It's easier to image how your problem looks

Comment: It's great if you can give me a debug repo ;)

Comment: debugger doesn't show any problems

Comment: I mean can you create a project with same problem and push it to github, after that give me the link. I want to debug it by myself

Comment: ok, I'll do it. Just uploaded a gif

Comment: Did you set constraint for the `gray/yellow` view below 100% label?

Comment: 100% label is pinned 8 pt to top of orange rectangle

Comment: How about orange rectangle leading, trailing and bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some excessive console printing I realized that this line of code:

```
upperContentHeightConstraint.constant = newUpperContentViewHeight
```

adds `newUpperContentViewHeight` to existing height constraint, not substitutes it. So the upper container view becomes almost twice as high. I have changed the line to:

```
upperContentHeightConstraint.constant = scrollOffsetY * -1
```

, which reduces view height by scrolling distance, and now everything works as intended.